# How do I set the active Build in xCode 5.0

Tags: iphone

I'v upgraded to xcode 5.0 and trying to get my app ready for release.  I made a copy of the release build and called it itunes.  I cannot figure out hoe to make my new build configuration, itunes, the active one, so when I do a Build, it will build base on my itunes build configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme. Then on the left sidebar select the type of build and on the right select the appropriate configuration.

[image]